# PGFPLOTS defintion inside macro inside table or insert boxplots inside table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, boxplot

I am trying to take a plot of a series of boxplots and include/insert these into a table. The code came from a posting of using a data table to define a series of boxplots. The code for the table inclusion requires the plot definition as a macro using `\newcommand`. Seems straight forward, but it is not. The code for the boxplot employs macros with parameters, so you have macros inside of macros. My first attempt replaced the `#1` with `##1` and `##1` with `####1`, but this would not compile. To complicate matters, I use layers (the background has 2 color rectangles which highlight the overall IQR which contrasts each years boxplot). My question revolves around a simpler method of drawing the boxplots and how could the main plot code be written as a macro that could be inserted into `\pgfplotstabletypeset` ? I included the base code MWE which draws the plot I need to insert into the table.
Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={thick},
             every tick/.append style={thick}}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/x axis shift up/.style={
    x axis line style={yshift=#1},
    xtick style={yshift=#1},
    xticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/y axis shift left/.style={
    y axis line style={xshift=-#1},
    ytick style={xshift=-#1},
    yticklabel shift={#1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch,
        make style readable from table=average
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
yr         lw     lq    med     uq     uw      av\\
1997     2.90   8.08   9.45  11.35  15.60   9.750\\
1998     2.40   8.50  12.50  18.00  51.30  13.910\\
1999     6.00   8.85  11.60  19.50  30.00  13.795\\
2000     7.70   9.50  15.00  20.50  41.10  16.671\\
2001     6.50  14.00  16.00  20.78  41.10  18.061\\
2002     7.40  14.83  18.50  25.83  42.00  20.825\\
2003    11.50  16.68  18.13  19.88  31.20  19.446\\
2004     4.40  12.21  15.14  16.83  20.20  14.053\\
2005     6.00   8.85  11.10  13.30  22.00  11.914\\
2006     3.50   8.23  12.70  15.90  17.80  11.875\\
2007     6.30   9.40  12.70  12.70  17.50  11.720\\
2008     2.00  15.10  16.50  20.00  32.10  17.311\\
2009     7.00  18.80  23.60  29.17  53.72  25.151\\
2010    11.00  21.75  26.52  30.88  42.10  26.373\\
2011    10.30  21.73  26.90  31.83  45.30  27.117\\
2012    12.20  17.48  21.90  26.98  40.30  23.170\\
2013    10.20  17.75  21.60  24.80  30.50  21.352\\
2014    12.50  21.45  24.80  32.50  38.70  26.180\\
}\datatable

\edef\desmu{19.06}
\edef\dessd{8.89}
\edef\lci{18.28}
\edef\uci{19.84}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\edef\ciline{1}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\edef\numberofticks{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[small, 
             boxplot/draw direction=x, ymin=0, width=9cm,
             height=9cm, clip=false,
             ytick={1,...,\numberofticks},
             xmajorgrids, major grid style=gray!20,
             xtick={0,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,60},
             yticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
             xmin=0, xmax=60, axis x line*=top,
             axis y line*=left, separate axis lines,
             x axis shift up=5pt, y axis shift left=15pt,
             xticklabel pos=upper, tick align=outside,
             xticklabel style={major tick length=0pt,
                        thick, color=black,tickwidth={5pt}},
             y axis line style={opacity=0}, y dir=reverse,
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofrows}{
  \addplot[
  boxplot prepared from table={
    table=\datatable,
    row= #1, %row=\i,
    lower whisker=lw,
    upper whisker=uw,
    lower quartile=lq,
    upper quartile=uq,
    average=av,%des
    median=med
  }, boxplot prepared,
    box extend=0.5,  % height of box
    whisker extend=0.5, % height of whiskers
    every box/.style={thin,draw=black,fill=gray!50},
    every whisker/.style={black,thick},
    every median/.style={black,thick},
    every average/.style={draw=red, /tikz/mark=* },
    /pgf/number format/precision=2
    ]
  coordinates {}
  node[left,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}}
  node[right,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}};
} %foreach

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[color=blue!10] (axis cs:12.2,\numberofticks) rectangle 
                        (axis cs:24.6,\ciline);
  \fill[color=red!10] (axis cs:\lci,\numberofticks) rectangle 
                        (axis cs:\uci,\ciline);
\draw [red,dotted,thick] (axis cs:\desmu,0.5) -- 
                         (axis cs:\desmu,\numberofticks)
   node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:\desmu,0.5){\tiny $ \mu$}
   node[blue,anchor=south east] at (axis cs:12.2,0.75)
                                   {\tiny $Q_1$}
   node[blue,anchor=south west] at (axis cs:24.6,0.75)
                                   {\tiny $Q_3$};
\draw [blue,dotted,thick] (axis cs:17.8,0.5) -- 
                          (axis cs:17.8,\numberofticks)
   node[blue,anchor=south east] at (axis cs:17.8,0.75)
                                   {\tiny $Q_2$};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209435/pgfplots-how-to-put-addplot-boxplot-prepared-inside-macro-definition (just to link the two questions)

Comment: My original attempt was to put the tikzpicture environment into a macro. The macro form is needed for inclusion of plot into a table. The code loops through the datatable. The related question is a hard coded version of the MWE above. So my question remains, how can I call the plot environment from a macro and still read data from table?