# PGFPLOTS: How To Put \addplot boxplot prepared Inside Macro Definition

Tags: macros, pgfplots, boxplot

I have a need to wrap the `\addplot [boxplot prepared]' inside a macro to greatly save typing. It seems simple enough, but the devil is in the details with macro expansion issues. Is this doable given PGFPLOTS ? I looked through the Programming Notes as well as the PGFPLOTS 1.11 Manual, with nothing coming up. I tried dumping the macro to the log file with the \meaning command. It gives me a 'Invalid character' message for every character in the macro. Not much use there. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Its frustrating something so fundamentally simple would bring a project to a dead stop. My MWE is below.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\newcommand{\desboxplot}[6]{
 \addplot[ boxplot prepared={
  lower whisker={#1}, lower quartile={#2}, median={#3},
  upper quartile={#4}, upper whisker={#5}, average={#6},
  box extend=0.5,  % height of box
  whisker extend=0.5, % height of whiskers
  every box/.style={thin,draw=black,fill=gray!50},
  every whisker/.style={black,thick},
  every median/.style={black,thick},
  every average/.style={draw=red, /tikz/mark=* },
  /pgf/number format/precision=2 } ]
  coordinates {}
  node[left,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}}
  node[right,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}};
} %end of \desboxplot definition

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
y=1.5cm,
]
\addplot+[
  boxplot prepared={
    lower whisker=5,
    lower quartile=7,
    median=8.5,
    upper quartile=9.5,
    upper whisker=10,
    box extend=2,  % height of box
    whisker extend=2.2, % height of whiskers
    every box/.style={very thick,dashed,draw=black,fill=yellow},
    every whisker/.style={red,ultra thick},
    every median/.style={densely dotted,cyan,ultra thick},
  },
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\ 1\\ 3\\
};
\meaning\desboxplot %{5}{7}{8.5}{9.5}{10}{9}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome at Tex.SX! You encountered a bug in `pgfplots`, sorry for that. I have fixed it; it will be gone in the next stable release. The workaround of @Jake repairs it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `%` at the end of the `\addplot[ boxplot prepared={` line.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\newcommand{\desboxplot}[6]{%
 \addplot[ boxplot prepared={%
  lower whisker={#1}, lower quartile={#2}, median={#3},
  upper quartile={#4}, upper whisker={#5}, average={#6},
  box extend=0.5,  % height of box
  whisker extend=0.5, % height of whiskers
  every box/.style={thin,draw=black,fill=gray!50},
  every whisker/.style={black,thick},
  every median/.style={black,thick},
  every average/.style={draw=red, /tikz/mark=* },
  /pgf/number format/precision=2 } ]
  coordinates {}
  node[left,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}}
  node[right,black] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},0.5)
  {\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}};
} %end of \desboxplot definition

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
y=1.5cm,
]

\desboxplot{5}{7}{8.5}{9.5}{10}{9}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. It still fails with this: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/boxplot/ lower whiske'. Seems like text is being lost in the expansion.

Comment: @user50506: Try eliminating the newline completely: `\addplot[boxplot prepared={lower whisker={#1},...`.

Comment: Jake, thanks for your help. I first tried the % after the first line with no success. After applying to the second line as well...success! Christian posted there is a bug here. Your help is greatly appreciated.